# Kernel Crash when using pyvista.PolyDataFilters.boolean_union()

Tags: python, crash, vtk, pyvista

I'm trying to combine two meshes of simple buildings such that they are "one" without enclosed surfaces. I tried to use the boolean_union operation provided by pyvista. This code works fine when using .merge():

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

building_1 = np.array([
[52.56, 42.43, 6],
[102.47, 42.43, 6],
[102.47, 12.13, 6],
[52.56, 12.13, 6],
[52.56, 42.43, 0],
[102.47, 42.43, 0],
[102.47, 12.13, 0],
[52.56, 12.13, 0]
])

building_2 = np.array([
[94.67, 12.13, 6],
[94.67, 0, 6],
[52.56, 0, 6],
[52.56, 12.13, 6],
[94.67, 12.13, 0],
[94.67, 0, 0],
[52.56, 0, 0],
[52.56, 12.13, 0]
])

building1_polydata = pv.PolyData(building_1)
building1_mesh = building1_polydata.delaunay_3d()
building1_surface = building1_mesh.extract_surface()
building1_triangulated = building1_surface.triangulate()

building2_polydata = pv.PolyData(building_2)
building2_mesh = building2_polydata.delaunay_3d()
building2_surface = building2_mesh.extract_surface()
building2_triangulated = building2_surface.triangulate()

test=building2_triangulated.merge(building1_triangulated)
test.plot(show_edges=True, opacity=0.5, color="gray")
```

but returns a mesh with enclosed surfaces. So I try to use the boolean_union operation which is designed to do what I want, but it leads to a kernel crash:

```
test=building2_triangulated.boolean_union(building1_triangulated)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. A collision is indeed detected when using:

```
building2_triangulated.collision(building1_triangulated)
```

so it should work? Why is this weird Kernel crash happening? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Boolean operations are often very finnicky. [The docs of the VTK filter](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter.html#details) explicitly warn about co-planar, overlapping cells. Your situation is very close. Doing something like `building2_triangulated.translate([1e-3, 1e-3, 1e-3]).boolean_union(building1_triangulated).clean()` gives something close, but the result is not manifold, there's an open edge where the two buildings should be merged. Changing to `.clean(tolerance=1e-2)` results in a manifold mesh but it has dangling points. I don't have a good fix.